# Cannot use string offset as an array in includes\form.inc on line 3575

Tags: forms

Before creating "form" custom module, everything was fine. After creating this module, I have got the following error message:

> Cannot use string offset as an array in includes\form.inc on line 3575

I deleted the entire custom module folder, and cleared the cache as well. Still, I am getting the same error when modules page.

How do I overcome this error?

coding inside the form.module page is

```
        function form_menu() {
      $items = array();
      $items['form/form'] = array(
        'title' => t('My form'),
        'page callback' => 'form_form',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'description' => t('My form'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      );
      return $items;
    }

    /**
    * This function gets called in the browser address bar for:
    * "http://yourhost/form/form" or
    * "http://yourhost/?q=form/form". It will generate
    * a page with this form on it.
    */
    function form_form() {

      // This form calls the form builder function via the
      // drupal_get_form() function which takes the name of this form builder
      // function as an argument. It returns the results to display the form.
      return drupal_get_form('form_my_form');

    }

    /**
    * This function is called the "form builder". It builds the form.
    * Notice, it takes one argument, the $form_state
    */
    function form_my_form($form_state) {

        // This is the first form element. It's a textfield with a label, "Name"
      $form['name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Name'),
      );
      return $form;
    }
```

Comment: Try disable/uninstall the module and clear the cache.

Comment: The OP said, "I deleted the entire custom module folder, and cleared the cache as well."

Comment: Somewhere in your form there is a property that should have a `#` in front of it. Without seeing your code it's impossible to help any further

Comment: Sounds like "everything is fine but motor is not working" case.

Comment: And when you say 'deleted', you did disable and uninstall it first right?

Comment: No. i didn't disable or uninstall the module, straight away deleted the folder.

Comment: @uma Doing that is never a good idea I'm afraid, no telling what it will break. Try removing the row for your custom module from the `system` table completely, that should reset it. But **make a DB backup first** of course

Comment: @Clive. Will never repeat this way of doing things hereafter. Deleting the content related to the custom module in system table solved the problem. Once again thank u so much.

Comment: @Clive It seems that, with your two comments, you answered the question. _Cough cough..._ `;)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno I know I'm terrible at doing that ;) I've put an answer in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the module folder outright, without uninstalling it through the UI/Drush (even manually in the DB) is bound to cause a few problems.

To get rid of any errors caused by Drupal thinking the module files are still there, you can simply delete the row in the `system` table which corresponds to the relevant module; but make a database backup first, of course.

In case you haven't come across the pages before, you can disable modules at http://mysite.com/admin/modules and uninstall them at http://mysite.com/admin/modules/uninstall through the UI, or use [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush).

Answer (score 0):

Run update.php after disabling that form module. My problem has been solved after doing this.